# Which layer actually contains attention and how to map with input for classification scenario

Tags: deep-learning, keras, attention-mechanism

I am writing a binary classification case and want to use Attention. The code is here - [Code](https://www.kaggle.com/sandeepbhutani304/attention-mechanism-effect-on-model-training) and model graph is shown below with attention area highlighted .
[image: Model with attention]

I want to visualize which which word is being paid attention by which hidden layer value. Now my questions are:

1. Which block in highlighted area should be used to match the attention with respect to input tokens?
2. I have tried `attention_weight` as the size is same as of `input` layer. But the attention is values are same in each 200 values.
3. I have tried `attention_vector` (Size 80) which contains different values for 80 cells. However, as this is not a Encoder-Decoder scenario, where multiple timestamps are representing different input tokens, my confusion is How to map hidden state value with tokens when both are present together. e.g. token=[1,4,2,10,3] attention_vector=[0.23, 0.11, 0.55] .. what kind of attention can be observed in these 2 vectors?